# Using a cell to fill out/finish a formula

Tags: google-sheets

So I am currently making a calculator, but need to make it as simple as possible. Currently I have it like this:

`=IFERROR(query('Calculator Data'!B:H,"Select F where C='105 Kira Tusami'", ""))`

If they want to calculate something else, they'd have to CTRL+F, and replace "105 Kira Tusami" with the number and the name of the person they need to calculate things for.

I am trying to find a way where they can type the number + name in to a cell, and it would automatically put that cell's content in to the formula.

So for an example:

Calculator!B6 = 105 Kira Tusami

`=IFERROR(query('Calculator Data'!B:H,"Select F where C='Calculator!B6'", ""))`

Obviously this doesnt work and I played around with it to see how I can get it to work, but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, it's often easier to use `FILTER`:

`=IFERROR(FILTER('Calculator Data'!F:F, 'Calculator Data'!C:C=Calculator!B6))`

However, if you wanted to stick with `QUERY`, write the `WHERE` clause like this:

`WHERE C='"&Calculator!B6&"'"`

If there will only ever be one possible match, then you'd be better off using `VLOOKUP`:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Calculator!B6,'Calculator Data'!C:F,4,FALSE))`